# How to use IMage validation in Symfony 2

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm validating an input field in Symfony 2 and I'm trying to use the Image validation, but it doesn't looks like it's working. It doesn't give me error way I put something else than an image or an image with the wrong size. He re is my code:

My entity:

```
<?php

namespace PublicBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Projet
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="pt_projet");
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PublicBundle\Entity\ProjetDepot")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Projet
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    //ID du projet
    protected $id;

     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProjetInt", cascade={"persist"}, mappedBy="projet", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    protected $descriptions;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pro_img", type="string", length=64, unique=true)
     */
    //Nom du fichier de l'image du projet
    protected $image;

    private $imageTemp;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pro_technologie_utilisee", type="text", length=200)
     */
    //Text qui liste tout les technologies utilisées pour le projet
    protected $technologie;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pro_annee", type="integer", length=4)
     */
    //Année de réalisation du projet
    protected $annee;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Type", inversedBy="projets")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="pro_type", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    //Clef étrangère du type de projet
    //Le type de projet ne correspond pas à la catégore. Il peu être Unity, flash, image, vidéo, etc. Il permet de savoir quelle page charger pour pouvoir intégrer le projet dans le portfolio.
    protected $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pro_fichier", type="string", length=64, unique=true)
     */
    //Nom du fichier du projet
    private $fichier;

    private $fichierTemp;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pro_largeur", type="integer")
     */
    //Largeur du projet
    protected $largeur;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pro_hauteur", type="integer")
     */
    //Hauteur du projet
    protected $hauteur;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Categorie", cascade={"persist"})
    */
    //La ou les catégories du projet
    private $categories;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->descriptions=new ArrayCollection();
        $this->categories=new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set image
     *
     * @param string $image
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function setImage($image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get image
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    /**
     * Set technologie
     *
     * @param string $technologie
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function setTechnologie($technologie)
    {
        $this->technologie = $technologie;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get technologie
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTechnologie()
    {
        return $this->technologie;
    }

    /**
     * Set annee
     *
     * @param integer $annee
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function setAnnee($annee)
    {
        $this->annee = $annee;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get annee
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getAnnee()
    {
        return $this->annee;
    }

    /**
     * Set fichier
     *
     * @param string $fichier
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function setFichier($fichier)
    {
        $this->fichier = $fichier;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fichier
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getFichier()
    {
        return $this->fichier;
    }

    /**
     * Set largeur
     *
     * @param integer $largeur
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function setLargeur($largeur)
    {
        $this->largeur = $largeur;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get largeur
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getLargeur()
    {
        return $this->largeur;
    }

    /**
     * Set hauteur
     *
     * @param integer $hauteur
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function setHauteur($hauteur)
    {
        $this->hauteur = $hauteur;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get hauteur
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getHauteur()
    {
        return $this->hauteur;
    }

    /**
     * Add descriptions
     *
     * @param \PublicBundle\Entity\ProjetInt $descriptions
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function addDescription(\PublicBundle\Entity\ProjetInt $description)
    {
        $this->descriptions[] = $description;

        //Set le projet dans la description immédiatement (nécessaire à cause du formulaire d'ajout de projet)
        $description->setProjet($this);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove descriptions
     *
     * @param \PublicBundle\Entity\ProjetInt $descriptions
     */
    public function removeDescription(\PublicBundle\Entity\ProjetInt $descriptions)
    {
        $this->descriptions->removeElement($descriptions);
    }

    /**
     * Get descriptions
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getDescriptions()
    {
        return $this->descriptions;
    }

    /**
     * Set type
     *
     * @param \PublicBundle\Entity\Type $type
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function setType(\PublicBundle\Entity\Type $type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get type
     *
     * @return \PublicBundle\Entity\Type 
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * Add categories
     *
     * @param \PublicBundle\Entity\Categorie $categories
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function addCategory(\PublicBundle\Entity\Categorie $categories)
    {
        $this->categories[] = $categories;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove categories
     *
     * @param \PublicBundle\Entity\Categorie $categories
     */
    public function removeCategory(\PublicBundle\Entity\Categorie $categories)
    {
        $this->categories->removeElement($categories);
    }

    /**
     * Get categories
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getCategories()
    {
        return $this->categories;
    }





    /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
     */
    private $fichierFile;

    /**
     * Sets fichier file.
     *
     * @param UploadedFile $fichierFile
     */
    public function setFichierFile(UploadedFile $fichierFile = null)
    {
        $this->fichierFile = $fichierFile;
        //Vérifi s'il y a déja un fichier de projet
        if(isset($this->fichier))
        {
            //Stock l'ancien nom pour l'effacer après la mise à jour
            $this->fichierTemp=$this->fichier;
            $this->fichier=null;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->fichier='initial';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get fichier file.
     *
     * @return UploadedFile
     */
    public function getFichierFile()
    {
        return $this->fichierFile;
    }





    /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
     */
    private $imageFile;

    /**
     * Sets image file.
     *
     * @param UploadedFile $imageFile
     */
    public function setImageFile(UploadedFile $imageFile = null)
    {
        $this->imageFile = $imageFile;
        //Vérifi s'il y a déja un fichier d'image
        if(isset($this->image))
        {
            //Stock l'ancien nom pour l'effacer après la mise à jour
            $this->imageTemp=$this->image;
            $this->image=null;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->image='initial';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get image file.
     *
     * @return UploadedFile
     */
    public function getImageFile()
    {
        return $this->imageFile;
    }



    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        //S'il y a un fichier pour le projet
        if (null !== $this->getFichierFile())
        {
            //Génère un nom unique
            $nomFichierProjet = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
            $this->fichier = $nomFichierProjet.'.'.$this->getFichierFile()->guessExtension();
        }

        //S'il y a un fichier pour l'image
        if (null !== $this->getImageFile())
        {
            //Génère un nom unique
            $nomFichierImage = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
            $this->image = $nomFichierImage.'.'.$this->getImageFile()->guessExtension();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        if (null !== $this->getFichierFile())
        {
            // if there is an error when moving the file, an exception will
            // be automatically thrown by move(). This will properly prevent
            // the entity from being persisted to the database on error
            $this->getFichierFile()->move($this->getUploadRootDirFichier(), $this->fichier);

            //Vérifi s'il y a déja un fichier de projet
            if (isset($this->fichierTemp)) {
                //Efface l'ancien fichier du projet
                unlink($this->getUploadRootDirFichier().'/'.$this->fichierTemp);
                //Efface le chemin temporaire
                $this->fichierTemp = null;
            }
            $this->fichierFile = null;
        }

        if (null !== $this->getImageFile())
        {
            // if there is an error when moving the file, an exception will
            // be automatically thrown by move(). This will properly prevent
            // the entity from being persisted to the database on error
            $this->getImageFile()->move($this->getUploadRootDirImage(), $this->image);

            //Vérifi s'il y a déja un fichier d'image
            if (isset($this->imageTemp)) {
                //Efface l'ancienne image du projet
                unlink($this->getUploadRootDirImage().'/'.$this->imageTemp);
                //Efface le chemin temporaire
                $this->imageTemp = null;
            }
            $this->imageFile = null;
        }  
    }



    /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeUpload()
    {
        $fichierFile = $this->getAbsolutePathFichier();
        if ($fichierFile) {
            unlink($fichierFile);
        }

        $imageFile = $this->getAbsolutePathImage();
        if ($imageFile) {
            unlink($imageFile);
        }
    }



    public function getAbsolutePathFichier()
    {
        return null === $this->fichier
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadRootDirFichier().'/'.$this->fichier;
    }

    public function getWebPathFichier()
    {
        return null === $this->fichier
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadDirFichier().'/'.$this->fichier;
    }



    public function getAbsolutePathImage()
    {
        return null === $this->image
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadRootDirImage().'/'.$this->image;
    }

    public function getWebPathImage()
    {
        return null === $this->fichier
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadDirImage().'/'.$this->image;
    }



    //Le chemin absolu du répertoire où le fichier du projet se trouve 
    protected function getUploadRootDirFichier()
    {
        return __DIR__.'/../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDirFichier();
    }

    //Le chemin absolu du répertoire où l'image du projet se trouve 
    protected function getUploadRootDirImage()
    {
        return __DIR__.'/../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDirImage();
    }



    protected function getUploadDirFichier()
    {
        return 'bundles/public/projets/'.$this->getType()->getNom();
    }

    protected function getUploadDirImage()
    {
        return 'bundles/public/projets/vignettes';
    }
}
```

My form:

```
<?php

namespace AdminBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

Class ProjetType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $constructeur, array $options)
    {
        $constructeur
        ->add('imageFile', 'file')
        ->add('technologie', 'text')
        ->add('annee', 'text', array('label'=>'année'))
        ->add('type', 'entity', [
            'class'=>'PublicBundle\Entity\Type',
            'property'=>'nom',
            'required'=>true,
        ])
        ->add('fichierFile', 'file')
        ->add('largeur', 'text')
        ->add('hauteur', 'text')
        ->add('categories', 'entity', [
            'label'=>'catégorie',
            'class'=>'PublicBundle\Entity\Categorie',
            'property'=>'tag',
            'required'=>true,
            'multiple'=>true,
            'expanded'=>true,
        ])
        ->add('descriptions', 'collection', array('type' => new ProjetIntType()));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'PublicBundle\Entity\Projet',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {  
        return 'projet';
    }
}
```

My validation:

```
PublicBundle\Entity\Infos:
    properties:
        lien:
            - AdminBundle\Validator\Constraints\ContrainteUrlExist: ~
        linkedin:
            - AdminBundle\Validator\Constraints\ContrainteUrlLinkedIn: ~

PublicBundle\Entity\Projet:
    properties:
        imageFile:
            - NotBlank: { message: "vide", groups: [creation] }
            - Image:
                minWidth: 600 
                maxWidth: 600
                minHeight: 400
                maxHeight: 400
                maxWidthMessage: "erreur"
                minWidthMessage: "erreur"
                maxHeightMessage: "erreur"
                minHeightMessage: "erreur"
        technologie:
            - NotBlank:
                message: "vide"
        annee:
            - NotBlank:
                message: "vide"
            - Regex:
                pattern: "/^[2-9]\d{3}$/"
                message: "date"
        fichierFile:
            - NotBlank: { message: "vide", groups: [creation] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation actually works. The problem was that I need to add 'Default' group in the validation because it was just checking the creation group.

Like this:

```
$formulaire=$this->createForm(new ProjetType(), $nouveauProjet, array(
                                                                          'validation_groups' => array('Default', 'creation'),
                                                                        ));
```